# How to convert query to Correlated Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, correlated-subquery

Struggle with correlated queries and wanted to know if someone could share a better example/explanation how to create a 'Correlated Query.' I do understand the inner/outer queries are dependent upon one another but still do not believe my solution is accurate or feel very sure when coding them and thought of practicing converting queries I have working to correlated. Here is example of working query:

```
SELECT p.productid, p.productname, SUM(od.unitprice - od.discount) * od.qty
  AS total_amount
  FROM Production.Products AS p
  JOIN Sales.OrderDetails AS od
  ON p.productid = od.productid
  JOIN Sales.Orders AS o
  ON od.orderid = o.orderid
  WHERE o.shipcountry = 'USA'; 

--EDITED--Converted to Correlated Query
```

So if I wanted to turn this into a correlated sub-query this should be the solution. Thanks for the guidance and advice.

```
SELECT productid, productname
FROM Production.Products AS t1
WHERE productid = (SELECT SUM(od.unitprice - od.discount) * od.qty AS
total_amount
     FROM Sales.OrderDetails AS od
         JOIN Sales.Orders AS o
     ON od.orderid = o.orderid
     JOIN Production.Products AS t2
     ON t2.productid = t1.productid
     WHERE o.shipcountry = 'USA')
GROUP BY productid, productname;
```

Thanks for the guidance and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are selecting from both products and orderdetails table, you should use the join based solution only:

```
select p.productid,
    p.productname,
    SUM((od.unitprice - od.discount) * od.qty)  as total_amount
from Production.Products as p
join Sales.OrderDetails as od on p.productid = od.productid
join Sales.Orders as o on od.orderid = o.orderid
where o.shipcountry = 'USA'
group by p.productid,
    p.productname
```

Note the added `group by` clause as you are using `sum` (also fixed).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT p.productid, p.productname,
       SUM(od.unitprice - od.discount) * p.qty AS total_amount
FROM Production.Products p JOIN
     Sales.Orders o JOIN
     Sales.OrderDetails od
     ON o.orderid = od.orderid
WHERE o.shipcountry = 'USA'
GROUP BY p.productid, p.productname;
```

A correlated subquery is not appropriate here.  You are returning results from multiple tables.  Just do the `JOIN`s correctly with a `GROUP By`.

Comment: unitprice and discount are in OrderDetails table for OP for some reason

Comment: yes, forgot to put the Group By there. Whether or not it would be appropriate does the second query meet Correlated sub-query (adding the Group by of course)? The productid from outer query matches the inner query and the result is added?

Comment: @allendks45 . . . I don't understand your comment.  This version has always had a `group by`.

Comment: I meant my original version. I was also seeking guidance if I wanted to turn this into a correlated query if there are any 'best practices' from the masters a novice could use. Despite finding a couple sites not many multi-tabled correlated subqueries for examples.